# write the domain without extension

Tags: dns

I found that sometimes when I write the name of a site it gets to the right website. for example when I write google I get google.com and when I write facebook I get facebook.com.
But when I write mohamedkadri I don't get mohamedkadri.com.

I thought That the browser uses the that name to get the site when it has been previously visited and cached, but I also visited mohamedkadri.com but mohamedkadri doesn't get mohamedkadri.com

How does this work? and who is the responsible for that, the host or the browser, or even the default search engine in my browser?

Thanks

Comment: Should be closed as off topic.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with programming.

Comment: then where to ask this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers use the 'feeling lucky' google search (or other search engines) to return the first result for a given keyword.

If you search on google for 'facebook' you'll get facebook.com as the first result.

If you search for 'mohamedkadri' you don't get 'mohamedkadri.com' as the first result.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to your browser to decide which site to access.  In the case of Firefox, the term for the address bar is the 'Awesome Bar', which uses a combination of search, history, and favorites to get you where you want to go [Here's some more information](http://blog.mozilla.com/blog/2008/04/21/a-little-something-awesome-about-firefox-3/)

I just did a little testing in Chrome, and it looks like I'm set to a google search if the tld is left off.  I'm not sure of the reaction of IE but I think it functions similarly to Chrome.